# Horizontal long list selector xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I have items coming from server dynamically and I need to create an `ItemTemplate` for those items.
I looked for ScrollViewer but I couldn't find ItemTemplate or ItemsSource property.

Is there a way to list items in phone:longListSelector horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

You can inside your Scrollviewer use a Listbox like this;

```
<ScrollViewer>
  <ListBox ItemsSource="your source" ItemTemplate="your template" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: If it worked, please set it as a answer. Otherwise tell me what's not working.

Comment: sorry some otherPages prioritys became higher I couldn't able to try it. I will give you an answer on monday I promise. thank you very much.